# Tomcat Server.xml XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: spring, tomcat, server.xml

I'm getting an error on Tomcat 4.0, XML document structures must start and end within the same entity, when running an application. I have checked that all tags are closed/linked, everything is fine when validating on Eclipse yet on Tomcat the error persist. Has anyone come across the before?

Comment: Missing info here, might be server.xml, context.xml or web.xml as invalid xml. Try this to find the broken one with `find /etc/tomcat -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -r0 -I '{}' xmllint -format '{}' > /dev/null`. Tomcat home under Eclipse is inside `.metadata` directory.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was with a missing tag I missed